RecyclerView Not Updating with Ketch Library Downloads in Android
I am using the Ketch library for managing downloads in my Android app. The issue is that while downloads are started successfully and appear in the notification bar, they do not update in the RecyclerView.
Here is a summary of my implementation:

The URL is fetched from the clipboard and displayed in a MaterialDialog for user confirmation.
After confirmation, the download is initiated using ketch.download(link, saveDir, fileName).
I observe the downloads using ketch.observeDownloads() and update the RecyclerView adapter (AdapterFile).

Despite all this, the RecyclerView remains empty or doesn't update correctly with the new downloads.
Here is my code:
HomeFragment:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentHomeBinding>() {
    override val bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater) -> FragmentHomeBinding
        get() = FragmentHomeBinding::inflate

    @Inject
    lateinit var adapterDownload: AdapterFile

    private lateinit var ketch: Ketch
    private val clipModel by viewModels<ClipBoardViewModel>()
    private var saveDir = ""

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        ketch = (requireContext().applicationContext as MyApp).ketch
        observer() // Observe downloads
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Save directory
        saveDir = requireContext().downloadDir(DOWNLOAD_DIR)

        // Observe clipboard data
        clipModel.clipData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { linkClip ->
            if (linkClip.isValidExtension()) {
                MaterialDialog(requireContext()).show {
                    customView(R.layout.add_download_file)
                    findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.txt_link).apply {
                        text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(linkClip)
                        isFocusable = false
                    }
                    findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.btn_positive).setOnClickListener {
                        val fileName = getFileNameFromUrl(linkClip) ?: ""
                        ketch.download(linkClip, saveDir, fileName) // Start download
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Set RecyclerView adapter
        binding.listDownload.apply {
            adapter = adapterDownload
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        }
    }

    private fun observer() {
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                ketch.observeDownloads()
                    .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                    .collect { downloads ->
                        adapterDownload.submitList(downloads)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

AdapterFile:
class AdapterFile @Inject constructor() :
    ListAdapter<DownloadModel, AdapterFile.ViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemDownloadBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemDownloadBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: DownloadModel) {
            binding.titleName.text = item.fileName
            binding.progressBar.progress = item.progress
        }
    }

    class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<DownloadModel>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: DownloadModel, newItem: DownloadModel): Boolean =
            oldItem.id == newItem.id

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: DownloadModel, newItem: DownloadModel): Boolean =
            oldItem == newItem
    }
}


What I’ve Tried:

Logged the data returned by observeDownloads(). The list contains the correct download items.
Verified that submitList() is called with the correct data.
Checked the implementation of DiffCallback, and it seems fine.


Problem:
The downloads show in the notification bar, but the RecyclerView does not update or show the download items.
How can I ensure the RecyclerView reflects the current download list? Is there anything I might be missing?
What Did You Try?

Logged the list of downloads returned by ketch.observeDownloads(). The list contains valid DownloadModel items, and the data seems correct.
Verified that submitList() is called with the data from ketch.observeDownloads().
Checked the implementation of the AdapterFile and ensured DiffCallback is correctly implemented.
Ensured the RecyclerView and its adapter are properly initialized in the Fragment.

What Were You Expecting?
I expected the RecyclerView to update and display the download items as they were being added or updated. Instead, the RecyclerView remains empty, even though the logs confirm that the list of downloads is populated.

lateinit var adapterDownload: AdapterFile is being instanced nowhere.

I don't understand what you mean. Thank you for being precise. The initial value is set in onViewCreated and the value is set in the observer.
